# Add in words after line split and loop it?

Tags: python, split

Can you add in wordings 'behind' after line split during/after the operation?

```
for line in fileLines:
    for word in line.split():
        print word

# OUTPUT:
1
0
0
-0.8
2
...
```

And now I wanted to add in a few different words such that it become like the following:
It will be the same amount of words that are going to be added in and it will just keep looping in this order (fL, fD, dep, AOV)

```
1 fL
0 fD
0 dep
-0.8 AOV
2 fL
...
```

Also, is it possible to achieve all this without having to create another file to store all this data? Like maybe store it somewhere in the memory etc and clear it once the operation is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), which takes in a list/iterable, and returns a new one which will loop infinitely. You can then use the `next()` builtin to get the next element from that infinite sequence.

```
import itertools

extra = itertools.cycle(['fL', 'fD', 'dep', 'AOV'])
for line in fileLines:
    for word in line.split():
        print word, next(extra)
```

If you want to store that information so you can iterate over the entire thing again, then simply do:

```
import itertools

data = []

extra = itertools.cycle(['fL', 'fD', 'dep', 'AOV'])
for line in fileLines:
    for word in line.split():
        text = next(extra)
        print word, text
        data.append([word, text])
```

Then later, you can do:

```
for word, text in data:
    print word, text
```

...to achieve the same exact output.

Just make sure you don't call `next` twice -- every time you do, you'll get a new element from `extra` instead of reusing the one you got.

Remember, how you store your data is completely separate from how you display it. If you do just `print data`, you'll probably get something that's relatively difficult to read. You'll need to write custom code if you want it displayed/printed out in a special way.

Comment: Pardon me, if I append the info (ignore my previous post), is there any ways that I can not make the output to be in this format - `[('-0.0116125', 'translateY'),
 ('1.01345', 'translateZ'),]` but instead to be the exact output as stated in your code without all those brackets etc?

Comment: You are fast. Actually I have just edited my comments as I managed to get the append thing but perhaps not in the format that I wanted to though..

Comment: @dissidia -- you'll have to write code/a function to print out the list in a custom way, I'm afraid. Often times, data is stored in a way which looks sort of ugly when printed -- you'll have to write code that goes through that data structure and display it in a less ugly fashion.

Comment: Noted about it. Well, now I am trying to export out the stored information, hopefully it will helps me should the list array not be working for me. Thanks!